# How to keep track of the user searched items by using cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

In my controller I am using this code to take user searched place in to a cookie.

```
$visitingPlace = $this->input->post('place_visiting');
        $cookie = array(
            'name' => 'searched_places',
            'value' => $visitingPlace,
            'expire' => '5184000',
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

this is only save one place if he searched for another place this is going to be override so how can I save all the places he is searching for. ?

Thank You.

Comment: You may have to use multi dimensional array i.e. `$cookie[$timestamp] = array(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$visitingPlace = $this->input->post('place_visiting');
$places         = unserialize( $this->input->cookie('searched_places') );   //all the searched cookies here
$places[]       = $visitingPlace;   //set the newly searched in the array
$cookie = array(
    'name' => 'searched_places',
    'value' => serialize( $places ),
    'expire' => '5184000',
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

First retrieve all the cookie values, unserialize them, place the new search in the array and then set the cookie again.

Comment: However, the maximum cookie size is 4KB. Use session instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the way to do this as Prava said I think this is a good way.

```
$visitingPlace = $this->input->post('place_visiting');
        $timestamp = now() + random_string('numeric', 5);
        $cookie[$timestamp] = array(
            'name' => 'searched_places',
            'value' => $visitingPlace,
            'expire' => '5184000',
        );
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```