# codeigniter cookie set using posted variable cant retrieve its values

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

In my index page I have a input field to enter a country or city name. then I post it to a controller and there I set it to a cookie and to a session (for testing).

```
$visitingPlace = $this->input->post('place_visiting');
        $timestamp = now() + random_string('numeric', 5);
        $cookie[$timestamp] = array(
            'name' => 'searched_places',
            'value' => $visitingPlace,
            'expire' => '5184000',
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($cookie);
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

and then load a search result page

```
$this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('top');
        $this->load->view('hotel_search_view');
        $this->load->view('footer');
```

In the search result page I am trying to get the cookie values, but it always return bool false

```
var_dump($this->input->cookie());
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
```

but the session is showing all the details.

```
bool(false) 

array(14) { ["session_id"]=> string(32) "4e940b327077d5ac23aea4ed8bef8a0a" ["ip_address"]=> string(3) "::1" ["user_agent"]=> string(109) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" ["last_activity"]=> int(1403675396) ["user_data"]=> string(0) "" [1403674268]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(3) "sss" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" } [1403674380]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(4) "vila" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" ["domain"]=> string(25) ".http://localhost/holasun" } [1403697663]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(3) "sss" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" ["domain"]=> string(25) ".http://localhost/holasun" } [1403754720]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(5) "dsdas" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" } [1403753967]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(4) "sfdf" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" } [1403770773]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(3) "sss" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" } [1403727272]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(5) "sdfdf" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" } [1403732164]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> bool(false) ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" } [1403754757]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(15) "searched_places" ["value"]=> string(2) "sd" ["expire"]=> string(7) "5184000" } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how you save data in cookie:**

```
<?php

$visitingPlace = $this->input->post('place_visiting');
$cookie = array(
    'name'   => 'searched_places',
    'value'  => $visitingPlace,
    'expire' => '5184000',
    'path'   => '/'
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

**This is how you retrieve the data from cookie:**

```
<?php

$cookie_value = $this->input->cookie('searched_places');
```

**This is how you save data in session:**

```
<?php

$visitingPlace = $this->input->post('place_visiting');
$this->session->set_userdata('searched_places', $visitingPlace);
```

**This is how you retrieve the data from session:**

```
<?php

$session_value = $this->session->userdata('searched_places');
```

For cookies [read the manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html).
For sessions [read the manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). Always read the manual!

Comment: it is something different than this.

Comment: No, its exactly like this how you need to set a cookie or session. Your code is not valid! I saw your other question. Use your brain. You already have the answer. And don't vote me down because I didn't give you the exact answer!

Comment: In my case I'm trying to save all the places the user is searching not only one place. as the way you have mention I can't save multiple places because it is overriding the previous one.

Comment: Thats why I said to use your brain. Use [Nil'Z](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24401096/1057527) answer and save the data in session serialized. And don't save it in cookie, as cookie has 4KB storage limit.

Comment: stackoverflow said without editing your answer I cant up vote.

Answer (score 1):

This `$this->input->cookie()` requires you to input a name to retrieve data, e.g,

```
 $this->input->cookie($timestamp); //for example

 $this->input->cookie('searched_places'); //for example
```

Comment: I tried $this->input->cookie('searched_places');
but still it showing bool(false)
and in my console it showing some hash values and size of 3883 under cookies

Comment: $this->input->cookie('searched_places'); now it is working using this.

Comment: Your answer helped me but machineaddict 's answer is the  complete answer. so I selected it as the answer.

Comment: i think, i have already answered a similar question of yours. have fun. :D